# HiddenInput(DisplayValue) needs to be in the CREATE View false but in the LIST View true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have an enum view model property which I want to hide in the CREATE View but show in the LIST/Index View. The enum is Open,Failed,Succeeded.

- For the CREATE View the editor/control should not be visible.
- For the LIST View the editor/control should be a selectable combobox

Can this be done somehow with the HiddenInput attribute?

If this can not be done then I want at least to make it visible in both views, but disabled/another control (label instead of combobox).

I am using asp.net mvc 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should be using different view models. Remember: the first word of *view model* is *view* meaning that you define a view model per view. So you will have a `CreateViewModel` that will be used for the `Create` view without the enum property in question and a `ListViewModel` with the enum property that will be used in the `Index` view.

When doing code reviews I see many developers trying to reuse the same models over different views and ending up with some horrible logic because those models simply are not adapted for those views. They try to hide, they try to write ifs and stuff to perform validation, usually end up in a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: In this case I agree with you Darin. See my question here could be interesting for you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146405/why-do-i-still-need-business-models-in-asp-net-mvc-when-a-viewmodel-does-all-the

Comment: one thing still came to my mind: When I use a ListViewModel AND CreateViewModel for my XXX-domain object then I will have a lot of duplicate properties in both ViewModels.